# Subscribing to webcal subscription via Outlook Desktop doesn't sync to other devices

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, calendar, webdav, subscription

**ISSUE**

When clicking on a webcal subscription URL, subscription events do not sync to other devices.

**METHOD OF SUBSCRIBING**
Clicking on a generated webcal:// link, which asked Windows 10 computers to launch Outlook. Once outlook is opened, it asks user to confirm calendar subscription.

**OBSERVATIONS**

- Subscribed Calendar immediately appears within Desktop Client on PC
- Subscribed Calendar does NOT appear in iPhone version of Outlook, or within OWA web.
- Within Outlook user prompt, within advanced option, "Display this calendar on other computers with the account" is enabled/checked.

**DEVICES**

Windows 10
Outlook for Office 365 MSO 64-bit Version 1906 (Build 11727.20244)

**GOAL**

- For users to be able to click a webcal subscription link, subscribe within Desktop Client, and have subscription events appear across all devices using same Exchange username.

Answer (score 0):

In my per experience, the method of subscribing a calendar with the webcal URL cant sync to other devices. For OWA, you could manaually resubscribe the webcal URL.

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/import-or-subscribe-to-a-calendar-in-outlook-on-the-web-503ffaf6-7b86-44fe-8dd6-8099d95f38df